# using constroptim in R on equals constraint on variables

Tags: r, optimization

The problem is simple.

I am using the constrOptim function wherein the constraints/parameters a,b,c satisfy the condition a+b+c = 1 and a>0,b>0,c>0

Can I have an example on this?

So far, I could code up something like this :

```
optim(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1),
   optimize_ranks,data=data,
   lower=c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.2),
   method="L-BFGS-B",
   upper=c(1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

All I want is, that these 6 params x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6 must add up to 1.

Comment: Does this answer satisfies your question this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to set these constraints (sum equals 1) on the 6 parameters `a`, `b`, `c` , `d`, `e`,`f` in `constrOptim`:

```
ui = rbind(
   c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
   c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)
 )
ci = c(0.999, -1.001)

func = function(x) x[1]-x[2]*x[1]+x[3]**3-x[4]*x[5]

init = c(1,0,0,0,0,0)

#> constrOptim(init, func, grad=NULL, ui=ui, ci=ci)
#$par
#[1]  -5744.485   4392.275 -27681.276  14950.497   5945.962   8138.027

#$value
#[1] -2.121093e+13
```

Think about your vector of 6 parameters `x` such that `ui*x>ci` (the inequality is strict, explaining the error margin of `0.001` in `ci`). It is exactly how it is described in `constrOptim` documentation.

Comment: so,if i have a,b,c,d,e,f and a+b+c+d+e+f = 1, i set ui = rbind(
       c(1,1,1),
       c(-1,-1,-1),
       c(1,0,0),
       c(0,1,0),
       c(0,0,1)
     ) and ci = c(1, -1, 0.00001, 0.00001, 0.00001) ? how about ci, i got the ui part though

Comment: Hey, could you suggest for the initial values for these 6 variables to start with? It says "initial value is not in the interior of the feasible region", when i start with c(1,0,0,0,0,0).

Comment: parameters <- constrOptim(c(0.00001,0.00001,0.00001,0.00001,0.00001,0.00001),optimize_ranks,data=data,lower=c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.2),method="L-BFGS-B",ui = rbind(
    c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
    c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1),
    c(1,0,0,0,0,0),
    c(0,1,0,0,0,0),
    c(0,0,1,0,0,0),
    c(0,0,0,1,0,0),
    c(0,0,0,0,1,0),
    c(0,0,0,0,0,1)
  ),
  ci = c(1, -1, rep(0.00001,6)))

Comment: It fails for the above call.

Comment: c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5) . even this doesnt work. how do i know the feasible region?

Comment: c(0.088, 0.088, 0.088, 0.088, 0.088, 0.333) ..now this must, must lie in the feasible region. still it gives the same error.

Comment: I know how to find the feasible region, but when i put some values out of it, it fails again, giving the same error - "initial values not inside the feasible region".

Comment: I cannot accept this as the right answer yet. Could you please help me with the initial parameters?

Comment: I edited my post, but please do not spam. Put your request in your question (which is badly formulated by the way since you speak about two problems and do not give the function to optimize).

Comment: I am still looking at it, I am reading the code now, for constrOptim, it at times says par empty, anyways I have found a work around to it, now have some other problem. thanks

Comment: Can you tell me how to pass a data frame in the f function to be minimized?that is the only thing aching me now.

Comment: Hum for this I need the detail of your function, the prototype at least. YOu can open a new question since it is very different to this one!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295794/pass-parametersdata-frame-in-controptim-in-r. I have asked this.