# pass parameters(data frame) in contrOptim in R

Tags: r, optimization

```
ui = rbind(c(1,1,1,1,1,1), c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1))
ci = c(0.999, -1.001)
init = c(1,0,0,0,0,0)

parameters <- constrOptim(theta=init,optimize_ranks,grad=NULL,data,ui = ui,hessian=FALSE,method=if(is.null(grad))"Nelder-Mead" else "BFGS",ci = ci,init=init)

optimize_ranks <- function(data,init)
{
 data$variance <- init[1]*((data$vs.rank - data$mew)^2) + init[2]*((data$gbu.rank - data$mew)^2) + init[3]*((data$vr.rank - data$mew)^2) + init[4]*((data$vre.rank - data$mew)^2) + init[5]*((data$vss.rank - data$mew)^2) + init[6]*((data$gbs.rank - data$mew)^2)
 weighted_variance <- sum(data$variance)

 #print(weighted_variance)

 return(weighted_variance)
}
```

The data frame data has all these columns, for sure. I am getting this error on this :

```
Error in data$vs.rank : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: You have an argument in your `constrOptim` called `data`. What is this variable? You haven't defined it.

Comment: when do you have this error? when you run constrOptim?

Comment: it should be data=data. data is the dataframe that goes as one of the inputs to the optimise_rank function.

Comment: you should fix your parameter data in your function with Curry from functional package to make it clear.

Comment: No, IT just used to work like a charm in Optim function.